# Selecting K largest values in a dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionary as below:

```
ls = [{'0': {'1': '1','2': '0.5','3': '1'},'1': {'0': '0.2','2': '1','3': '0.8'},}]
```

I would like to select k-largest values with their keys for each key of dictionary (ls). I have written below commands. It just gives me the k-largest keys without their values.

**Python Code:**

```
import heapq
k=2
for dic in ls:
    for key in dic:
        print(heapq.nlargest(k, dic[key], key=dic[key].get))
```

**Output**

```
['2', '3']
['3', '1']
```

I need to have value of each selected key.

Answer (score 3):

- First of all, I just wanted to check why you have

  `ls = [{'0': {'1': '1','2': '0.5','3': '1'},'1': {'0': '0.2','2': '1','3': '0.8'},}]`

  This is a list containing a dict, which doesn't match your description in the question.
- Here is a solution that uses dict comprehensions that should give you what you want :)

  ```
   def get_n_largest_vals(n, d):
       x = {key: heapq.nlargest(len, map(int, d[key])) for key in d}
       return {key: map(str, x[key]) for key in x}
  ```

  Here it is being used for your problem:

  ```
  ls = [{'0': {'1': '1','2': '0.5','3': '1'},'1': {'0': '0.2','2': '1','3': '0.8'},}]
  d = ls[0]
  get_n_largest_vals(2, d)
  >>> {'0': ['3', '2'], '1': ['3', '2']}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
from operator import itemgetter
for d in ls:
    for key, d2 in d.items():
        print(dict(heapq.nlargest(k, d2.items(), key=itemgetter(1))))
```

Notice that your *values* are still *strings* so they'd be lexically ordered, which is not what you want, because `'2' > 12'` And the dictionary is not ordered!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The way you suggested works, but I need to have the output as a dictionary as following:{'2': '1', '3': '0.8'}